# sed delete a line matching a pattern with special characters

Tags: sed

I'm not real familiar yet with using sed, and am trying to delete this line in an apache .conf file:

`"%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"`

I've attempted many different variations of something similar to this, with no luck so far:

`sed '/\%t \%h/d' /etc/apache2/conf.d/ssl.conf`

but always end up with this error:

> sed: bad option in substitution expression

I know I'm missing something very easy here, but I've run out of patience dealing with it (you know how it goes), lol.

Anyone?

Comment: That error only makes sense if the sed command has an `s` before the match pattern, and your example doesn't show that.  It should not output that error unless it's doing substitution... that is a command starting with `s` and having three delimiters.   Also, percent should not need escape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to delete the entire lines, `fgrep -v` may be a better option:

```
fgrep -v '%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x "%r" %b' /etc/apache2/conf.d/ssl.conf
```

but if it truly needs to be sed, this should work:

```
sed 's/%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x "%r" %b//' /etc/apache2/conf.d/ssl.conf
```

Comment: Thanks DudeBro (lol), the second one mostly worked for me, with some tweaks, but ultimately I ended up figuring out a way to do it using the `d` "switch", like this: `sed -i '/.*%{SSL_PROTOCOL}x.*/d' /etc/apache2/conf.d/ssl.conf`. Your answer did result in solving my issue though, and you're new here, so I figured you could use the points. =)

Comment: Nice!! Glad I could at least point ya in the right direction :) @J.ScottElblein